# Why does the 'join' method for Seq object in Biopython not work on the last element of a list?

Tags: biopython

The code below is from the Biopython tutorial. I intend to add 'N*5' after every contig. Why is the trailing N*10 not present after the third contig "TTGCA"?

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq 
contigs = [Seq("ATG"), Seq("ATCCCG"), Seq("TTGCA")] 
spacer = Seq("N"*10) 
spacer.join(contigs) 
output
Seq('ATGNNNNNNNNNNATCCCGNNNNNNNNNNTTGCA')

expected output
Seq('ATGNNNNNNNNNNATCCCGNNNNNNNNNNTTGCANNNNNNNNNN')
```

Doesn't the index in Python and Biopython both begin with 0?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with biopython.

This is just how string.join works:

```py
configs = ["ATG", "ATCCCG", "TTGCA"] 
spacer = "N"*10 
spacer.join(configs)
```

Result:
ATGNNNNNNNNNNATCCCGNNNNNNNNNNTTGCA

As it should - according to `help(str.join)`:

> join(self, iterable, /)
> Concatenate any number of strings.
>
> The string whose method is called is inserted in between each given string.
> The result is returned as a new string.
>
> Example: '.'.join(['ab', 'pq', 'rs']) -> 'ab.pq.rs'

Comment: '  '.join(['Thank','you', 'Lydia', 'van', 'Dyke'])